# gwt - mvp design

Tags: gwt, mvp

I'm new to gwt and I'm making an app with header, left-side navigation bar, a menu on top and a panel where I going to show the content.

The content panel will have a lot of custom widgets, and the user will can move them, so I'm using gwt-dnd library.

How should I desing the UI?

- Should I put menu, navigation bar and content in the same widget? or Should them be different widgets?
- Do the mvp apply just to the container views in the content panel or the custom widgets inside them should use mvp too?
- Any other ideas?

thx a lot!!!!!!

Comment: Have you done *any* research on this before coming down here asking to basically design your whole application's architecture? :/ There are [numerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt+mvp) questions on this topic. If you have a specific question about MVP, with some code or *any work done*, please feel free to ask it then.

Comment: Yes, I did a research (and I think there is no enough info for newbies) and I have a lot of code. Initially I didn´t use mvp, now I'm trying to implement mvp on the ui code I did. But yesterday I got so confused so I wanted to clear some basic doubts here. But don´t worry, I'm trying in other sites too...

Comment: Well, if you do have a lot of code, you could post some info about - for example, you want to know if you should put menu, nav bar and content in the same widget... *It depends* is the answer to that question - unless you give us some more details about your project and said widgets :) I don't want to discourage you from asking questions here (or anywhere else), but right know this question boils down to "How should I design the UI using MVP?" - and there's simply no one answer to that question.

Answer (score 4):

David, take a look to this excelent example: http://95.110.143.4/layoutmvp/layoutmvp.html

The source is here: http://95.110.143.4/layoutmvp/layoutmvp.tar.gz

And here is posted by the code owner in GWT group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!searchin/google-web-toolkit/multiple$20activities/google-web-toolkit/C6S4jS1UsM0/_mZnqA6lVrAJ

Regards!